# Update YAML file using shell script in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, shell, yaml, ubuntu-16.04

I have to update YAML file configuration. Below are the current and expected output. How can I do it using shell script in a better and simplest way?

Before update of the YAML file:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
```

After update of YAML file:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: "wiredTiger"
#  mmapv1:
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 4
```

Comment: You should always use a parser to do that kind of updating, using a shell script (calling `sed` or `awk`) that doesn't know about YAML internals is guaranteed to break at some point. (On quotes, folded lines, comments, block vs flow style, etc.)

Comment: Pretty much in agreement with @Anthon there. I mean "It's just text" so you can do pretty much anything you want. But it actually is a "serialized data structure", so really it makes a lot of sense to parse and modify a data structure to your requirements and then output it again as YAML. It's almost age old since even CSV can be pretty simple, and yet it's also really simple to break it. Data structures are generally best left to things that understand them. IHMO,

Comment: As a sidenote,  your "edits" are really quite generic. So there does not seem to be any reason why you can simply not swap out an existing configuration for a new one. Unless of course there is some instance specific data contained which is not mentioned in the question,

Comment: @Anthon what is the best parser to use it for my scenario?

Comment: Since you have comments in your YAML, I recommend ruamel.yaml (i am the author of that Python package). It is the only parser I know of that tries to preserve comments and key ordering. You can pass the size as a commandline parameter, should not take more than 10-15 lines of Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input is in `config_in.yaml`:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

You can call `python update.py wiredTiger 4` with `update.py`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from ruamel.yaml import YAML

file_name = Path('config_in.yaml')

engine = sys.argv[1]
size = int(sys.argv[2])


yaml = YAML()
data = yaml.load(file_name)
data['storage']['engine'] = engine
data['storage'][engine] = dict(engineConfig=dict(cacheSizeGB=size))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
yaml.dump(data, Path('config.yaml'))
```

to get this output (on stdout as well as in `config.yaml`):

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: wiredTiger
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 4
```

This assumes Python3 (or Python2 with pathlib2 installed), and ruamel.yaml (of which I am the author)

Comment: engine: "wiredTiger" is missing in output. Also I don't want this line "# wiredTiger:" . Here is my output after execution of your script. # Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 4
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

Comment: I updated the script. It **is** possible to delete comments, but not as easy as leaving them out as in the input I presented. Especially because multiple comment lines are assumed to be one comment block.